# __get and __set magic methods not accessible

Tags: php, class, magic-methods

I have a class 'base' and a class 'loader', which looks like this.

```
class base {

    protected $attributes = Array();   
    public $load = null;           

    function __construct() {

        $this->load = loader::getInstance();  
        echo $this->load->welcome(); //prints Welcome foo
        echo $this->load->name; //prints Foo
        echo $this->name; //doesnt print anything and i want it to print Foo

    }


    public function __get($key) {

        return array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes) ? $this->attributes[$key] : null;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {

        $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
    }
}

class loader {

    private static $m_pInstance;       

    private function __construct() {

        $this->name = "Foo";

    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$m_pInstance) {
            self::$m_pInstance = new loader();
        }

        return self::$m_pInstance;
    }

    function welcome() {
        return "welcome Foo";
    }

}

$b = new base();
```

Now what I want is a way to store variables from loader class and access them from base class using `$this->variablename`.

How can I achieve this? I don't want to use `extends`. Any idea ?

Comment: Your `loader` class instance should be passed in via `base`'s constructor.

Comment: I am passing that and saving the loader class instance in base class variable 'load' by using $this->load = loader::getInstance();

Comment: That's not the same; passing it in via the constructor is cleaner.

Comment: Sorry @Jack, i didnt get that. Can you explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your __get/__set methods access `$this->attributes` but not `$this->load`.
You could e.g. do something like (pseudocode)

```
function __get($key) {
  - if $attribute has an element $key->$value return $attribute[$key] else
  - if $load is an object having a property $key return $load->$key else
  - return null;
}
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/property_exists

Answer (score 2):

I don't feel like you've fully understood what coding the OOP way means. And usually Singletons are code smells so I'll just warn you:

There's probably a better way of accomplish you goal. If you provide more informations we will help you out. In its current form the answer is the following; just remember that I **higly discourage** its implementation in your code.

Assuming that you want to access only public (and non static) `loader`'s variables as `this->varname` in the `base` class you should just insert this line in the beginning of the base class constructor:

```
$this->attributes = get_object_vars(loader::getInstance());
```

This will basically initialize the attributes array with all the loader public vars so that via your `__get()` method you can access its value.

*On a side note, take a look at [Dependency Injection design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) in order to avoid using Singletons.*

Comment: As an extension to this, in this instance, you should pass in the exact variables from "loader" which are required by the "Base". These generic names also hint at code smell, what exactly are they for?

Answer (score 0):

You can make static variable and then you can access this variable from anywhere

```
public statis $var = NULL;
```

and you can access it like this

```
classname::$var;
```